# What is wrong with this C code? I want to know the number of 1s in the input string

Tags: c++, c, string, scanf, gets

I want to get the number of 1s(as a character) in the input string but its not working. Please tell me the reason.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"string.h"

int main()
{
  int n,l,count1=0,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  char a[n];
  gets(a);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(a[i]=='1')
      count1++;
  }
  printf("%d",count1);
  puts(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `std::cin` and algorithms. It will be a lot easier.

Comment: Yep, first question is: Do you want to do this in C or C++.

Comment: @stefan this is C code

Comment: @Hephaestos it's tagged with `c++`.

Comment: change to ` scanf("%d%*c",&n);char a[n+1];`

Comment: Umm... what do you think `scanf("%d", &n)` does ?

Comment: @stefan It has been wrote **"this C code"** in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will skip gets() because of the new line character you entered earlier , newline character is a delimiter for gets() . though using a getchar() right after scanf should work but i will recommend using this

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"string.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int n,l,count1=0,i;
scanf("%d",&n);
char a[n];
std::cin>>a;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]=='1')
        count1++;
}
printf("%d",count1);
std::cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is C code, so std::cin and std::cout and iostream are not available.

Comment: This is C code, so the definition of a variable, on the stack, is only available immediately after a '{', so the OP must be using a C++ compiler.  However, it is not valid C code.

Comment: Question is tagged with c++

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this question with C++ and there is an easy way to solve this in C++:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::count
#include <iostream>  // for std::cin and std::cout
#include <string>    // for std::string

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s; // reading in the string
    auto n = std::count(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), '1'); // counting '1' characters
    std::cout << "the number of '1's in the string \"" << s << "\" is: " << n << "\n";
}
```

[Click here for a demo.](http://ideone.com/4J76ZA)

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, then replace `auto` by `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not take into account The end of the string (`'\0'`) characters secured.
2. the actual input is not a newline entered in `scanf` is consumed in `gets`.
3. Number of characters actually entered might be smaller than `n`.
4. `gets` might have caused the overflow. (It is obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

Old fashioned 'C':

```
int ch ;
int count = 0 ;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if (ch == '1')
      count += 1 ;
  } ;
```

(Untested !)

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
char a[n];
gets(a);
```

is wrong, it's too small a buffer since there's no room for the terminator which `gets()` will put there.

Never do this. In fact, never use `gets()` for anything.

Instead, do

```
char line[256];

if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
{
  printf("read a line, process here\n");
}
```